# How do I create a new SQL table with custom column names and populate these columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I currently have an SQL statement that generates a table with the most frequent occurring value as well as the least frequent occurring value in a table. However this table has 2 rows with the row values as well as the fields. I need to create a custom table with 2 columns with min and max. Then have one row with one value for each. The value for these columns needs to be from the same row.

```
(SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS frequency 
 FROM firefighter_certifications 
 GROUP BY name 
 ORDER BY frequency DESC limit 1) 
UNION 
(SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS frequency 
 FROM firefighter_certifications 
 GROUP BY name 
 ORDER BY frequency ASC limit 1);
```

So for the above query I would need the names of the min and max values in one row. I need to be able to define the name of new columns for the generated SQL query as well.

```
Min_Name | Max_Name
Certif_1 | Certif_2
```

Comment: What results do you want if there are ties for the minimum and/or maximum values?

Answer (score 1):

I think this query should give you the results you want. It ranks each name according to the number of times it appears in the table, then uses conditional aggregation to select the min and max frequency names in one row:

```
with cte as (
  select name,
         row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as maxr,
         row_number() over (order by count(*)) as minr
  from firefighter_certifications
  group by name
)
select max(case when minr = 1 then name end) as Min_Name, 
       max(case when maxr = 1 then name end) as Max_Name
from cte
```

Comment: I have not copied it from your answer. I have deleted it. Until OP put the expected output in the question I was not sure what OP wanted.

Comment: @zealous don't expect you to delete yours just pointing out that it is now the same.

Comment: I totally understand but your answer is the expected answer that OP need, so that is fine.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Postgres doesn't offer "first" and "last" aggregation functions.  But there are other, similar methods:

```
select distinct first_value(name) over (order by cnt desc, name) as name_at_max,
       first_value(name) over (order by cnt asc, name) as name_at_min
from (select name, count(*) as cnt
      from firefighter_certifications
      group by name
     ) n;
```

Or without any subquery at all:

```
select first_value(name) over (order by count(*) desc, name) as name_at_max,
       first_value(name) over (order by count(*) asc, name) as name_at_min
from firefighter_certifications
group by name
limit 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=75613c8abcfdee9a1d5669020d9a7c04) is a db<>fiddle